# connection from one list to another

Tags: connection

I have one list for inserting the data and one of the fields is connected to another list where I have supplier details.
After one item was inserted into the list what I also see is in front of the company name number on the list (e.g. 1;#Poland).
How can I get rid off that 1;# sign in front of name?

Many thanks in advance for help

Comment: Lookup columns store the ID of the lookup value in the form ID;#text, but this ID is not displayed in normal OOTB views. Where are you surfacing this?

Comment: Hi @SebastijanStrasek if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@ransher-singh is correct. This should not normally appear. I have seen this when working with Workflows. If you are using workflows look at this:

> In SharePoint Designer, when you pick the column you want from the
>   current item, there should be three drop-down boxes. The bottom one
>   should be "Return field as:" and you can choose to return the Lookup
>   IDs or the Lookup Values.

Source: [retreive multi value lookup values in sharepoint 2010 workflow](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/90528/retreive-multi-value-lookup-values-in-sharepoint-2010-workflow)

You should change the "Return field as:" dropdown to "Lookup values". This is the option which will provide you with only the text.